# How to restore backup postgres database on windows machine

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

I have tried on terminal:

> ```
> psql -d test < .\backup_database.sql
> ```

```
At line:1 char:14
+ psql -d test < .\backup_database.sql
+              ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

`pg_dump` command worked seamlessly on terminal.
So where do i run `psql` command.
Tried on `dbshell`-Not working, Manually adding on `pgadmin 4` gives `pg_restore: error: input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use redirection on Windows, use the `-f` parameter to pass the file to be run:

```
psql -d test -f backup_database.sql
```